# I would like to print out a vector of character in R that can then be directly called in the console and print, is that possible with paste0?

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
> vec <- c("firstone", "secondone")
> vec
[1] "firstone"  "secondone"
```

I would like to manupulate `vec` to print `c("firstone", "secondone")` verbatim in R. Is paste0 useable for this?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Do you want `cat(capture.output(dput(vec)))`?

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, thank you!`

Comment: Why `cat` and `capture.output` though? `dput(vec)` gives the same thing.